# Downloading and saving images from https URLs in android

Tags: android, image, ssl, download

I have this function that downloads and saves images in device -

```
public void DownloadFromUrl(String WebURL, String fileName) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(WebURL);
            file = new File(context.getFilesDir() + fileName+".jpg");

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
            int current = 0;
            while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                baf.append((byte) current);
            }
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("ImageManager", "Error: " + e);
        }
    }
```

If I supply an **https** URL, it cannot save the image. Any pointers on how to download and save **https** images ?

Comment: It cannot save the image? But it can download it? What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Do not use that intermediate `ByteArrayBuffer`. You can directly write to the file output stream.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Picasso or Glide. It is super easy to use. And the best part is that it does automatic disk and memory caching, so you do not have to worry about anything.
[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) - check out this link.
OR
[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)  - check out this link.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this link will help you. Uploading/Downloading Pictures by Tonikami.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLe60o7ed8E-Q7tqKNPnWFdUoeniqH_-A9

Answer (score 0):

The only mistake I made above is that I was trying to download and save large images when connectivity was slow. Some of my images are around 5-10 MB. Otherwise the code is fine.